# Collapse/expand child nodes of tree in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, hierarchy, force-layout

I'm building a tree structure (or rather modifying one of the examples with a set of my own data in my own json) and I'm trying to create some functionality:

My tree's layout is that from the tree example:
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/cluster.html

I am adding (to the circles) an onclick event which I would like to collapse the children of the clicked node.  That is to say, when a user clicks the steelblue circle associated with a node, I want that nodes children to disappear.

I've scoured the documentation and I haven't turned up anything which would allow me to make nodes collapse or disappear.

What could I do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's this:

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

There are a number of other interactive hierarchical layout examples from my [SVG Open keynote](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/).

Comment: Agree. Thank you, beautiful tool. I would give it a +2 if I could

Comment: @mbostock thanks so much for the wonderful visualization. The version of your work at https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083 might be easier for other users to adapt

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple approaches, one is just to use regular stying to hide the markup of the children (opacity: 0, or display: none).  However, this just makes the data invisible, the tree maintains its shape as if the data is there, you just can't see it.

Usually you'll want the tree to pretend the data isn't there and update accordingly, for that you can use the same approach as the force-directed layout example in the above link.

It boils down to:
1) Use a function to build the d3 tree
2) append a click event to the collapsible nodes
3) The click event renames the children property of the node and calls the function in 1) which redraws the tree without that node's children.

Here's the relevant code from the link in nkoren's answer ( http://bl.ocks.org/1062288 ):

```
function update() { 
    // build the tree layout here
    //  append on("click", click) to the collapsible nodes
}

// Toggle children on click
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I'm still getting up to speed with D3, and am not sure how to best answer your question. But Here's a force-directed layout which allows you to show/hide nodes by clicking on them, which might give you some ideas: http://bl.ocks.org/1062288

Comment: Forced directed layout is good for graph visualization but it is not ideal for trees.

Comment: If you look through the source you can see that it doesn't matter that it's a force-directed layout, the same solution could be used for any DAG (i.e., no loops in the graph), which includes trees.  I'll add the specific code in a specific answer (in case the link ends up breaking).

Answer (score 1):

Create a collapse function that will be executed upon click only when node has children. I've shared the code below that worked for me:

```
  collapse = (d) => {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach((d) => this.collapse(d));
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  click = (d) => {
    console.log('click: ', d);
    if (d.children) {
      this.collapse(d);
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    this.updateChart(d);
  }
```