# How to remove a single child node in tree layout

Tags: d3.js

This is for a tennis draw and I need to be able to have a bye, so most parents have two children, ie. winner of each match goes through, but in some cases there is a bye, so there is only one child.  See here as an example where some parent matches have no children and some have one: http://www.irtpa.com/index.php/realtennis/ladder/1246

I don't think this answer helps: [How to remove node on tree layout D3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636240/how-to-remove-node-on-tree-layout-d3-js/13641135#13641135)

As it is assuming that ALL children of a node are hidden/removed.

I've got this far based on the above stackoverflow answer but my brain cannot see the solution for removing/hiding the child:

```
function check_children(data, parent) {
// recurse through array and toggle/hide any Match Byes

  if (typeof data.data != "undefined") {
    if (data.data.bye == "byeM") {
        toggle(parent);
    }
  }

  if (data.children) {
    check_children(data.children[0], data);
    check_children(data.children[1], data);
  }

}

function toggle(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do? Do you want to promote a child to take the place of a parent? Getting rid of the lines in toggle that use _children should permanently remove those children from the tree. Maybe you could post a jsFiddle and/or some before-and-after json objects for what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to remove just one of the children, not both as most examples show.  So the _children trick doesn't work.  It's a rather substantial piece of code so was hoping someone might say - That's easy, just....!  After having a break from this problem I might try another approach, seeing if I can use the separation in the layout to hide one under the other.

Comment: Ok - so when you call toggle(parent) you want to instead remove a specific child of parent? Or remove parent from the list of children that it is contained in?

Comment: Remove a specific child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove your "bye" children I would probably test before recursing. So something like:

```
function removeByeChildren(parent) {
  if(!parent.children)
    return;

  var i = 0;
  while(i < parent.children.length) {
    var data = parent.children[i].data;
    if (typeof data != "undefined" && data.bye == "byeM") {
      // remove child - could save it in _children if you wanted to ever put it back
      var child = parent.children.splice(i,1);
      // length of child list reduced, i points to the next child
    }
    else {
      // not a bye - recurse
      removeByeChildren(parent.children[i]);
      // all the child's bye's are removed so go to the next child
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

You can play with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/6pSFC/). The idea is to check each child if it is a bye or not. If it is we remove it from the list and if it is not we recurse and remove all the descendant child byes.

Comment: That looks very promising.  Will have a go in the morning.