# D3 force layout collapsing issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/juanlacueva/u6vhxyen/) D3 instance. I'm trying nodes to collapse and hide its childrens when click but I'm getting "Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node." when I click one.

Since the error happens on d3.js I'm having a big trouble debugging it.

Here's the code

```
window.onload=function(){


var width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(.2)
    .charge(-500)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(250);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")   
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var root = getData();
var nodes = flatten(root),
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.x = width/2 + i;
    d.y = height/2 + 100 * d.depth;
});

root.fixed = true;
root.x = width / 2;
root.y = height / 2;

force.nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .start();

var link = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
   .enter()
    .insert("svg:line")
    .attr("class", "link");

var gnodes = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
     .data(nodes)
     .enter()
     .append('g')
     .classed('gnode', true);

var node = gnodes.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr('data-name', function(d) { return d.name; })
      .attr("r", 25)
      .style("fill", '#FFFF44' )
      .call(force.drag)
      .on("click", click);;

var labels = gnodes.append("text")  
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr('class', 'etiqueta')
      .text(  function(d) { return d.name; } );





force.on("tick", function(e) {

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
/*
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
*/
         gnodes.attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')'; 
    });

});

function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update();
}


function update() {
    console.log('updating');
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update the links…
  link = svg.selectAll("line.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links.
  link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  // Exit any old links.
  link.exit().remove();

  // Update the nodes…
  node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
      .style("fill", color);

  node.transition()
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? 4.5 : Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10; });

  // Enter any new nodes.
  node.enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? 4.5 : Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10; })
      .style("fill", color)
      .call(force.drag)
      .on("click", click);

  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();
}



function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [];
    function recurse(node, depth) {
        if (node.children) {
            node.children.forEach(function(child) {
                recurse(child, depth + 1);
            });
        }
        node.depth = depth;
        nodes.push(node);
    }
    recurse(root, 1);
    return nodes;
}



function getData() {
    return {
        "name": "flare",
            "children": [{
            "name": "analytics",
                "children": [{
                "name": "cluster",
                    "children": [{
                    "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
                    "size": 3938
                }, {
                    "name": "CommunityStructure",
                    "size": 3812
                }, {
                    "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
                    "size": 6714
                }, {
                    "name": "MergeEdge",
                    "size": 743
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "graph",
                    "children": [{
                    "name": "BetweennessCentrality",
                    "size": 3534
                }, {
                    "name": "LinkDistance",
                    "size": 5731
                }, {
                    "name": "MaxFlowMinCut",
                    "size": 7840
                }, {
                    "name": "ShortestPaths",
                    "size": 5914
                }, {
                    "name": "SpanningTree",
                    "size": 3416
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "optimization",
                    "children": [{
                    "name": "AspectRatioBanker",
                    "size": 7074
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "animate",
                "children": [{
                "name": "interpolate",
                    "children": [{
                    "name": "ArrayInterpolator",
                    "size": 1983
                }, {
                    "name": "ColorInterpolator",
                    "size": 2047
                }, {
                    "name": "DateInterpolator",
                    "size": 1375
                }, {
                    "name": "Interpolator",
                    "size": 8746
                }, {
                    "name": "MatrixInterpolator",
                    "size": 2202
                }, {
                    "name": "NumberInterpolator",
                    "size": 1382
                }, {
                    "name": "ObjectInterpolator",
                    "size": 1629
                }, {
                    "name": "PointInterpolator",
                    "size": 1675
                }, {
                    "name": "RectangleInterpolator",
                    "size": 2042
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "ISchedulable",
                "size": 1041
            }, {
                "name": "Parallel",
                "size": 5176
            }, {
                "name": "Pause",
                "size": 449
            }, {
                "name": "Scheduler",
                "size": 5593
            }, {
                "name": "Sequence",
                "size": 5534
            }, {
                "name": "Transition",
                "size": 9201
            }, {
                "name": "Transitioner",
                "size": 19975
            }, {
                "name": "TransitionEvent",
                "size": 1116
            }, {
                "name": "Tween",
                "size": 6006
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "data",
                "children": [{
                "name": "converters",
                    "children": [{
                    "name": "Converters",
                    "size": 721
                }, {
                    "name": "DelimitedTextConverter",
                    "size": 4294
                }, {
                    "name": "GraphMLConverter",
                    "size": 9800
                }, {
                    "name": "IDataConverter",
                    "size": 1314
                }, {
                    "name": "JSONConverter",
                    "size": 2220
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "DataField",
                "size": 1759
            }, {
                "name": "DataSchema",
                "size": 2165
            }, {
                "name": "DataSet",
                "size": 586
            }, {
                "name": "DataSource",
                "size": 3331
            }, {
                "name": "DataTable",
                "size": 772
            }, {
                "name": "DataUtil",
                "size": 3322
            }]
        }]
    };
}
}
```

Comment: you havent defined color on your JSFiddle link :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collapse/expand child nodes of tree in d3.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541511/collapse-expand-child-nodes-of-tree-in-d3-js)